# Python 2, 3 Mac dependencies

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pip

I'm really getting confused between these different versions for Mac. I want to use Python 3 but that's causing errors using pip.

So now every time i have to install a dependency I must use the command

```
sudo pip install dependency --upgrade --ignore-installed six
```

Even this installs the dependency for python 2 and not 3.

Can anyone please suggest what I should do to just default to python 3 all the time and be able to install any dependency with just

```
pip install dependency
```

I'm using Macbook Pro 2010 with Mac OS sierra

Comment: Try with `pip3`. If that doesn't work, call Python 3's `pip` explicitly `python3 -m pip ...`

Comment: You should setup a virtualenv using python3, activate it and work from there. Don't install extras directly in the systems python (2 or 3), you are likely to break a system utility depending on Python